# Creating a login check that allows two ways of web application access

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an older web application that we are still using.

Some users are starting to use a newer .Net Core Entity Framework app that uses its API to connect to the backend of this older app.

So on the new app, I created an API endpoint that sends the users apiID to the older app.

Then, on the old app, I wrote this little function that looks for that apiID and makes sure that the connection is allowed:

```
Protected Function sec_IsSecureAPI() As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("apiID")) Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

And I use it in the Page_Init function like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If sec_IsSecureAPI() Then
        ' let the user in...
    Else
        ' redirect to login page
    End If
End Sub
```

So it works for API users, but it's blocking those users who still use the old system directly.

Is there a way I could make it so the old system can differentiate between an API user and a regular user?

Thanks!

Comment: So, guessing the old api doesn't' have the apiID query parameter?  Will the new API ever NOT have the apiID query parameter?

Comment: @Hursey thanks, yeah the old system will never use apiID.  But the new system will ALWAYS use it when trying to connect.  thanks!

Comment: So you could you use the presence of apiID as the flag to indicate if the request has come from either system.  If request.QueryString Contains apiID then new authentication, else old authentication